# Update manifest splash icon on PWA converted to APK

Tags: google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps, google-play-console, trusted-web-activity

I've converted a PWA website into an Android app by using https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/ convertor.

The splash icon looks pixelated for some reason. I've tried updating the manifest.json file with the correct icon at 512x512 but changes don't seem to get reflected on the installed app.

I've uninstalled the app, installed it again and did that connected to Wifi and with the phone plugged. Nothing changes.

I'm wondering if perhaps, as I've converted the PWA into a APK now I need to release a new version of the app on Google Play Store in order to update anything regarding `manifest.json`.

And if not, how do I force an update on the splash icon?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, you will need to generate a new APK and release a new version to the Play Store. The reason is that the splash icon is part of the Android application and is generated when the Android package (APK) is created.

The bad news is that, unfortunately, `pwa-to-apk` doesn't offer the functionality of regenerating the package, and generating a new package for the same PWA will not work since, when updating the application to the Play Store, it must be signed with the same key used to sign the original package.

The good news is that it does allow the developer to download **the certificate** used to sign the application. If you downloaded the certificate and took note of the key alias and passwords, you will be able to generate a new package with the same name, using the original keys.

[image]

With the key saved to your file system, the alias, store password and key password at hand, you can use[Bubblewrap CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/cli) to regenerate the project. Check out the [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start).

A few additional instructions:

- When Bubblewrap ask for the **`Application ID`**, ensure you are using the same ID used on the Play Store. The id can be seen in the Play Store URL for the application. As an example, the ID for `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.pwa_directory` is `com.appspot.pwa_directory` and you need to use this value as the application id.
- When Bubblewrap ask for **`Key store location`**, type in the path to the keystore file downloaded from pwa-to-apk.
- When Bubblewrap ask for **`Key name`**, use the value of the alias generated by pwa-to-apk. The alias defaults to `android`.
- Finally, when running `bubblewrap build`, use the key password and store passwords provided by pwa-to-apk.

With this, Bubblewrap will generate a new package that will not only contain the updated icon, but also uses the latest and greatest libraries available.